# How to resolve storage (HDD Disk) not found issue

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-detection

My laptop has recently been in strange problems. It has two internal disks: one HDD and one SSD. The SSD still functions normally, while the HDD occasionally cannot be detected. After some time, the HDD is detected again, and some time after that, it is removed again. This error is extremely annoying. When I got to the warranty, they told me that the HDD had problem and replaced it with a new one (I doubted it a lot), but then the same problem keeps happening again and again. It happens on both OS Windows and Linux. In summary, the HDD can be suddenly removed or detected any time, making usage on this disk is very difficult

Comment: If replacing the drive did not solve the problem then it could be an issue with the motherboard or connector. You should try to gain access to the drive and connector while the system is running so you can see if moving it around is what’s causing the issue. You can hear a HDD power up and power down as well. If so, you should explain the issue and get it repaired under warranty. Especially if it’s the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you or the people replacing HDD have checked the connections properly. This problem happened to me too. In my case I just put some paper spacer behind the HDD to ensure that contacts are firmly attached to the motherboard and it worked fine.